# how to override function in register page in the aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am intend to override the function in my aspx, in my page , i have the follow register page

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebLITE" TagName="HeaderControl" Src="~/ctrl/HeaderControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebLITE" TagName="FooterControl" Src="~/ctrl/FooterControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebLITE" TagName="NavigationControl" Src="~/ctrl/NavigationControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebLITE" TagName="FunctionTabControl" Src="~/ctrl/FunctionTabControl.ascx" %>
```

On the navigation page, there is a log out button, on the current page, i am intend to override that function, because there is some unique action i need to do during log out.

This is the source on the navigation page

```
Protected Sub Logout(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Session("LoggedIn") = Nothing

        Session.Clear()
        Session.Abandon()
        Session.RemoveAll()

        Response.Cookies("SessionId").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) 
        Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("SessionId", ""))

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx")
    End Sub
```

what i did is put the following code in the page,

```
Public Overridable Sub Logout(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

However it seem does not working well, is there anyone can provide me the solution for this?

Comment: why can't you just add to the existing logout function? Or make a function that's called by it? This stuff is a template provided for you to use and change, not some untouchable code.

Comment: because if i add to existing log out function, how i am going to verify which page that i sent request from to execute the special condition function

Comment: why does it matter which page requested the logout? Logout should be the same wherever it is requested from. If there's something that needs to be done during logout, it should always do it. You can't guarantee which page the user will be on when they decide to logout. In a web app, you can't even guarantee that the actually _will_ press the logout button, they might just close the browser. If the session expires while the browser is closed, that extra action will never happen anyway - so you might need to consider some extra background service to do a "clean up" as well, if it's vital.